# Three.js: Updating Geometries vs Replacing

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I have a scene with lots of objects using `ExtrudeGeometry`. Each of these need to update each frame, where the shape that is being extruded is changing, along with the amount of extrusion. The shapes are being generated using d3's voronoi algorithm.

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/x00xsdrt/)

Right now I am achieving this by removing every object from the scene and redrawing them each frame. This is very costly and causing performance issues. Is there a way to edit each mesh/geometry instead of removing from the scene? Would this help with performance? Or is there a more efficient way of redrawing the scene?

I'd need to edit both the shape of the extrusion and the amount of extrusion.

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to come up with a way of not having to redraw the scene every time and it massively improved performance.

http://jsfiddle.net/x00xsdrt/4/

This is how I did it:

1. Created a "template geometry" with `ExtrudeGeometry` using a dummy
   10 sided polygon.
2. As before, created a bunch of "points", this time assigning each
   point one of these template geometries.
3. On each frame, iterated through each geometry, updating each vertex
   to that of the new one (using the voronoi alg as before).
4. If there are extra vertices left over, "bunch" them up into a single           point. (see http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates.)

Looking at it now, it's quite a simple process. Before, the thought of manipulating each vertex seemed otherworldly to me, but it's not actually too tricky with simple shapes!

Here's how I did the iteration, `polycColumn` is just a 2 item array with the same polygon in each item:

```
// Set the vertex index
var v = 0;

// Iterate over both top and bottom of poly
for (var p=0;p<polyColumn.length;p++) {

    // Iterate over half the vertices
    for (var j=0;j<verts.length/2;j++) {

        // create correct z-index depending on top/bottom
        if (p == 1) {
            var z = point.extrudeAmount;
        } else {
            var z = 0;
        }

        // If there are still legitimate verts
        if (j < poly.length) {

            verts[v].x = poly[j][0];
            verts[v].y = poly[j][1];
            verts[v].z = z;

        // If we've got extra verts, bunch them up in the same place
        } else {

            verts[v].x = verts[v - 1].x;
            verts[v].y = verts[v - 1].y;
            verts[v].z = z;
        }

        v++;
    }
}

point.mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not changing the number of faces, you can use morph targets http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html

You should

1. Create your geometry
2. Clone the geometry and make your modifications to it, such as the maximum length of your geometry pillar
3. Set both geometries as morph targets to your base geometry, for example

   baseGeo.morphTargets.push(
     { name: "targetName", vertices: [ modifiedVertexArray ] }
   );

After that, you can animate the mesh this using mesh.updateMorphTargets()

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. It might not apply here as I'm using d3's voronoi algorithm to generate the shapes. These can have any number of sides (usually around 4 or 5). Also, there is no easy way to predict what each shape will look like, so I'm not sure if tweening between each state would work. Do you think morphing with a frame-by-frame approach would still improve performance?

Comment: see: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates. "You can only update content of buffers, you cannot resize buffers (this is very costly, basically equivalent to creating new geometry).

You can emulate resizing by pre-allocating larger buffer and then keeping unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden."

Comment: I've recently been doing big re-topology work using web workers, you might try looking into that if you think the performance is going to bite you. Basically, generate your geometry in a web worker, and on the post event add that back to your scene and remove the old one.