# verticesNeedUpdate in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use dat.GUI to manipulate the coordinates of a mesh vertices.

At first I thought I could have removed every frame my meshes to recreate them anew, but then I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203598/three-js-updating-geometries-vs-replacing) that it's not a good way.

Is verticesNeedUpdate that I should use? It seems not to be on Three.js documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your geometry is `THREE.Geometry`, then your can update the vertices by using a pattern like so:

```
geometry.vertices[ 0 ].set( x, y, z );

geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

If your geometry is `THREE.BufferGeometry`, then you can use this pattern:

```
geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, x, y, z );

geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

In either case, you only need to set the `needsUpdate` flag if the geometry has been previously-rendered.

Also, you cannot resize buffers;  you can only change the data values. See the Wiki article [How to Update Things](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things) for additional information.

three.js r.85

Comment: Thanks. I'm using THREE.Shape() and moveTo/lineTo