# THREE.js dynamically add points to a Points geometry does not render

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, points

I am using Three.js r83.

I am trying to dynamically add points to a geometry, but the scene never gets updated.

This works :

```
var tmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    size: 5,
    opacity: 1
});

var tgeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var pointCloud = new THREE.Points(tgeometry, tmaterial);

for(var i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
    x = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    y = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    z = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    tgeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
}
tgeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
tgeometry.computeVertexNormals();

scene.add(pointCloud);
```

This doesn't work:

```
var tmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    size: 5,
    opacity: 1
});

var tgeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var pointCloud = new THREE.Points(tgeometry, tmaterial);
scene.add(pointCloud);

for(var i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
    x = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    y = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    z = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
    tgeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
}
tgeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
tgeometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
tgeometry.computeVertexNormals();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

As you can see, the only difference is the fact that  I add `scene.add(pointCloud);` before adding vertexes.

What do I miss?

You can find a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjjaLv3e/2/)  Thanks to @hectate

To see what I means, just replace

`init();
setPoints();
animate();`

by

`init();
animate();
setPoints();`

Comment: What is your version of three.js? Check also documentation [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) on how to update things...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699389/verticesneedupdate-in-three-js/36699654#36699654 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically/31411794#31411794.

Comment: @WestLangley I am currently exploring the BufferGeometry, it seems like the number of points is fixed though.

Comment: The max number is. The rendered number is not. Study the 2nd link I posted.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks - I got it working with the maximum points and a BufferGeometry. Updating and writing an answer now.

Comment: From trial and error method, requesting animation frame before rendering this one, is like the worst thing you can do, just wrong, at your own risk there. and if true, why has no one noticed?

Comment: @greenthings I guess you're probably right - I haven't touched 3.js for more than 3 years - so I can't recall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why the `THREE.Geometry` object doesn't update Points after initial rendering, but I got it working with a `THREE.BufferGeometry` instead.

Thanks to `@Hectate` who got a working fiddle for me and `@WestLangley` who directed me to the hints, [here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjjaLv3e/19/)

BufferGeometry has a fixed number of Vertices, but you can decide how many of them you want to render. The trick is to make use of `geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;` and `geometry.setDrawRange( 0, nbPointsYouWantToDisplay );`

```
var MAX_POINTS = 1000000;
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var positions = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); 
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
```

Then you can create your cloudpoints and add it to the scene:

```
//material and scene defined in question
pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(pointCloud);
```

Now I want to add and render `500` new points every `10` milliseconds.

```
var nbPoints = 500;
var INTERVAL_DURATION = 10;
```

All I have to do is :

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  setPoints();
}, INTERVAL_DURATION)

function setPoints() {

  var positions = pointCloud.geometry.attributes.position.array;

  var x, y, z, index;

  var l  = currentPoints + nbPoints;
  if(l >= MAX_POINTS) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  for ( var i = currentPoints; i < l; i ++ ) {
    x = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 300;
    y = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 300;
    z = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 300;
    positions[ currentPointsIndex ++ ] = x;
    positions[ currentPointsIndex ++ ] = y;
    positions[ currentPointsIndex ++ ] = z;
  }
  currentPoints = l;
  pointCloud.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;   
  pointCloud.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, currentPoints );  
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Comment: three.js moved away from `Geometry` in favor of `BufferGeometry` as you found out. Of course that's easy for me to say in 2021 ( ;

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fiddle with your first setup installed: https://jsfiddle.net/87wg5z27/236/

```
var scene, renderer, camera;
var cube;
var controls;

init();
animate();

function init()
{
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize (width, height);
    document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.y = 160;
    camera.position.z = 400;
    camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);

    var tmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      size: 5,
      opacity: 1
   });

   var tgeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   var pointCloud = new THREE.Points(tgeometry, tmaterial);

   for(var i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
     x = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
     y = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
     z = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
     tgeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
   }
   tgeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
   tgeometry.computeVertexNormals();

   scene.add(pointCloud);

   window.addEventListener ('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize ()
{
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate()
{
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame ( animate );  
    renderer.render (scene, camera);
}
```

Here's one with your second: https://jsfiddle.net/87wg5z27/237/

```
var scene, renderer, camera;
var cube;
var controls;

init();
animate();

function init()
{
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize (width, height);
    document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.y = 160;
    camera.position.z = 400;
    camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);

    var tmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      size: 5,
      opacity: 1
    });

    var tgeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var pointCloud = new THREE.Points(tgeometry, tmaterial);
    scene.add(pointCloud);

    for(var i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
     x = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
     y = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
     z = (Math.random() * 200) - 100;
     tgeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
    }
    tgeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    tgeometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
    tgeometry.computeVertexNormals();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    window.addEventListener ('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize ()
{
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate()
{
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame ( animate );  
    renderer.render (scene, camera);
}
```

In both cases the point cloud shows for me perfectly fine (release 82). Perhaps there is something else missing where you're neglecting to render something? I notice that your first example doesn't show at what step you call render(). I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Hectate, Thank you very much for the fiddle, I should have created one - really thank you. I did another fiddle that shows case my problem - see updated question. https://jsfiddle.net/jjjaLv3e/2/

I want to update the PointCloud after it has been rendered.