# three.js[83] points vertices update not work

Tags: javascript, three.js

example here:https://plnkr.co/edit/GWSuAbmSGHv4o75WK2Rj?p=preview

Update vertices of geometry and nothing happens.But verticesNeedUpdate is setted to true.Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('update');
  starsGeometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0));
  starsGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
},2000)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177425/three-js-dynamically-add-points-to-a-points-geometry-does-not-render

Comment: @gaitat Thanks a lot and, could you tell me how to find it? I have tried to search for various combinations of keywords.

Comment: find what? which keywords?