# update indices of a bufferGeometry in three.js

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I have updated vertices of a BufferGeometry in Three.js. However, after that update, the indices of that bufferGeometry also need to be updated in my case. I just use `geometry.setIndex(newIndicesArray)` command without success. I am not sure if I need to enable any update flag for index. Thank you.

Comment: `geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;` - three.js rev: 82

Comment: Thank you Rasheduzzaman. I added that to the code. It is interesting that when I open the geometry, the indices is the new array, but the geometry shown is not based on it!

Answer (score 1):

You want to update the indices of your indexed-`BufferGeometry` after the geometry has been rendered.

To do so, you cannot reassign a new index array -- you can only change the values of the existing array.

Consequently, you must use this pattern:

```
mesh.geometry.index.array[ 0 ] = 10;

mesh.geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;
```

For how to update vertices, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699389/verticesneedupdate-in-three-js/36699654#36699654).

three.js r.84

Comment: Thank you WestLangley. I now know that I can only update the numbers without just inputting a new Array. However, having done that, I can see the index numbers have been updated from the console, but the geometry is surprisingly based on previous index, and not changed!

Comment: Hi Westlangley. I just want to make a flat square to a flat square with a hollows in the middle. I have defined a slices=4, stacks=4 surface. However, for this transformation, the indices should be updated, in other words, reduced down, which seems impossible for BG. I was wondering if you have a comment on this. Thank you.

Comment: You need to accept this answer, make a new post, and show your code -- preferably with a live example. This answer explains how to update indices and vertices. You cannot resize the arrays.