# How to manipulate geometries vs. meshes in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry

I have methods that will loop through a geometries' vertices and move them to new locations. For example, I can rotate the geometry around an arbitrary axis in space by rotating each point around that axis.

So if I have a mesh displayed using the geometry, how can I update the mesh as I manipulate the locations of the vertices?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36699654/1461008

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to figure that out for weeks. Looks like you have to use the .set() method or else it won't update the mesh positions/orientations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159

Answer (score -1):

This example would move the geometry up 5 units in the positive Y direction, mesh would follow it if verticesNeedUpdate is set to true on the geometry after every time it is updated:

```
// Update geometry vertices however/whenever you would like
geometry.vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
    vertex.set(vertex.x, vertex.y + 5, vertex.z);
 });

//Tthen, this must be called inside animation loop (each frame or whenever updated)
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Not sure why it is down-voted, but this is the solution that works

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use [Geometry.translate()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Geometry.translate) if you need to offset the geometry. The code would look like so for your use case:

```
geometry.translate( 0, 5, 0 );
```

However, transforming the geometry should be normally a one-time operation. For ongoing transformation (within the animation loop), modulate `Object3D.position`, `Object3D.rotation` and `Object3D.scale` instead. Otherwise you will have a noticeable negative impact on your performance (depending on the geometry's complexity).

`three.js R108`

Comment: Doesn't help because that only lets me translate entire geometries. For example, I am looping through vertices and rotating the vertices around an arbitrary axis, not translating.